# Adding Code into Theme Customizer Header

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

I use the Theme Customizer pretty extensively and I want to add some Javascript code into the Customizer .

How do I go about doing this? Can't figure it out for the life of me...

Thanks!

Comment: you mean the customizer itself?

Answer (score 2):

You use the `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` action hook for that. Then you enqueue script as usual. Like this:

```
function wpse256911_customizer_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-customizer', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-customizer.js', array( 'jquery', 'customize-controls' ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse256911_customizer_enqueue' );
```